# Sendgrid and laravel 5 mail send and receive

Tags: laravel-5.1, sendgrid

I'm currently building a new version of an older website of mine and I'm trying to make a function that allowes users of mine to receive and send emails via that application. So they are be able to log in and send e-mails to another e-mail adress. Also if I sent an email to my domain I want to be able to receive the mail and have a catchall option. I'm currently using Laravel 5.1 and SendGrid.

I really don't know how to receive e-mails. The sending works.

Answer (score 1):

Use this library.

[Laravel sendgrid library](https://github.com/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver)

You can simply install like this.

Add the package to your composer.json and run composer update.

```
"require": {
    "s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver": "5.0.x-dev"
},
```

Comment: Sending e-mails works, except the receiving, but I think I might have found it.